# JavaScript Express - How to take dynamic form requests

Tags: javascript, express

I have a dynamic form using EJS and Express in which the user can choose to add more images by clicking a button,

[image]

The response works, however for data storing purpose, I want each image response to be stored together in a single array. As this is dynamic, how do I iterate through each of the image form response in order to store tham in an array? as users may only put 1 image, making checking for every single request a bit redundant?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = [];

function addImage(file) {
    images.push(file);
}
function removeImage(file) {
    images = images.filter(img => img != file);
}
```

When a customer clicks submit button, this arrya value (images) would be submitted.